# How to parse an exact value from JSON object in Java?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I'm using an API to return price rates. It returns this:

```
    {
        "nzd_usd":{
        "high":0.69920002,
        "low":0,
        "avg":0.34960001,
        "vol":85.31394798,
        "vol_cur":124.37162356,
        "last":0.69917777,
        "buy":0.62000500,
        "sell":0.69917777,
        "updated":1515692771
    }
}
```

which I'm able to set to be displayed in a textview but what I need is to extract some info only to display it like the last price. I used the code like in the screenshot below:
[image]
Unfortunately it returns:

```
01-11 19:46:32.178 10723-10723/com.app.rates W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for last
```

I understand it's because it doesn't access the object but I'm not sure what to do at this stage.

Comment: If you use something like `retrofit` to make your API requests then you can set things up so that json is automatically serialized to/from Java objects (using `gson` library)....you can also use `gson` directly if needed

Comment: Because last is float but not string and inner object of nzd_usd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly get the `last` JSON, you need to first get `nzd_usd` JSONObject and then retrieve `last` out of it.

```
String last = object.getJSONObject("nzd_usd").getString("last");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject("nzd_usd");
        String last = json.getJSONObject("last").toString();
        System.out.println(last);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Still it gave:
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value nzd_usd of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject